# Upload image file not working in Laravel vuejs

Tags: php, html, laravel, vue.js

I'm going to upload my image file to storage folder through laravel vuejs ,
but now I just tried to print the data through `dd();` but it returns no response and no error how should I suppose to know if I doing correctly or not?

I think the error insists through `formData` when passing the data through Ajax with this

```
data: {form_data:formData, ........
```

**input file**

```
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" id="file" ref="file" name="profile_avatar" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg"  v-model="card_image_main" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
```

**vuejs**

```
module.exports = function(data) {
var _data = {
    file: '',
};
return {
    data: (() => Object.assign({}, data, _data)),
    props: {
        data_object: Object,
    },
    mounted() {
        this.init();
    },
    methods: {
        init() {
            var vm = this;
            var t;
        },

    updateMain(){
      let vm = this;
      this.file = this.$refs.file.files[0];
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', this.file);
      this.$refs.file.value='';

      $.ajax({
         url: vm.$route('staff.ajax.emvvalidationdetails.updatemain'),
         type: 'POST',
         headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'), 'undefined': 'multipart/form-data'},
         data: {form_data:formData, emvdetailsdata: vm.emvdetailsdata[0], other_ext_name: vm.other_ext_name, other_contact_name: vm.other_contact_name},
         success: function (response) {
             if (response) {
                 vm.emvdetailsdata = response;
            
                 }},
               });
                document.getElementById("EditForm").submit();
             }
       }
```

**routes**

```
Route::post('updatemain', 'EmvvalidationdetailsController@updatemain')->name('staff.ajax.emvvalidationdetails.updatemain');
```

**EmvvalidationdetailsController**

```
public function updatemain(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with installing Telescope and checking the request

Comment: What do you mean installing Telescope?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/telescope -> watchdog

Answer (score 0):

Uploaded files are treated differently by the server than other form data. When a file is uploaded via a form, it is sent as a binary stream, not as a string, and it requires special handling to be processed properly. The `$request->file()` method takes care of this handling for you, whereas the `$request->get()` or `$request->all()` method does not. by updating your controller code like this you should be able to see the uploaded file and store it:

```php
public function updatemain(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('file');
    // dd($file);
    $file->store('public/src/');
}
```

Comment: the problem is when I add my formdata inside data like this   `data: {form_data:formData`   there's no response at all even error or success message, even I used `dd` nothing happens

Comment: When The problem insist on that line did I initialize it correctly?

Comment: i usually do `const form = new FormData();` then add file `form.append('photo', image);` then send post request `axios.post('/api/me/photo', form)` and i obtain the file like this `this.$refs.photo.files[0]` witch `photo` is a ref to `<input ref="photo" type="file"`. nothing more